# Cursive, lowercase ell

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What is the easiest way to make a cursive, lowercase ell in LaTeX math mode?

Comment: Impressive: three answers, all the same, all within three minutes!

Comment: For general information how to find a specific symbol see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol/21#21

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Simply use `$\ell$`

Answer (score 31):

Well `\( \ell \)`

Comment: and +1 for using `\( ... \)`

Comment: @Stefan: What's the advantage of using `\( ... \)`?

Comment: @doncherry: Have a look at [Inline math: $…$ vs. \(…\)](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/inline-math-mode/).